# How to make a word counter program using Python?

Tags: python

I need to create a program that reads a text file and prints the following:

1. All the unique words in the text
2. The number of times they appear in the text
3. The total number of words

---

```
from collections import Counter
count = 0

file = open(r"sample_input.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8-sig")
wordcount = Counter(file.read().split())

for item in wordcount.items():
    print("{}\t-\t{}".format(*item))
```

Output should looks like this:

```
WORD FREQUENCY 
can - 1
grow - 1
and - 1
shrink - 1
on - 1
demand - 1 
TOTAL = 6
```

My program counts the lower case and uppercase differently. Is there a way to filter out punctuation?

Comment: I think it would be good if you provided a small sample input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When creating your list of words, convert them to lowercase via [str.lower](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower)

```
from collections import Counter

wordcount = Counter()

#Open the file
with open(r"sample_input.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8-sig") as file:

    #Iterate through each line
    for line in file:

        #Strip any trailing or leading whitespaces
        line = line.strip()
        #Iterate over the words and keep updating counter
        for word in line.split():
            wordcount.update([word.lower()])

for key, value in wordcount.items():
    print("{}\t-\t{}".format(key, value))

#Sum up the count of words
num_words = sum(wordcount.values())
print(num_words)
```

The output will be

```
can - 1
grow - 1
and - 1
shrink - 1
on - 1
demand - 1
6
```

Comment: It gives me "<generator object <genexpr> at 0x03793C70> -1" when I run the program?

Comment: Rather than read all the words in the file and then create the counter, wouldn't it be more memory efficient to first create the counter and then update it with the words? `c = Counter(); 
for word in words: c.update([word.lower()])`

Comment: Hi @Devesh i'm using phython 3.7, it doesn't say which line.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! I'm really a newbie when it comes to programming. I appreciate the help guys. How do I add a total number of words?

Comment: Hi @Devesh, I need help with a new program, can you assist me again?

Comment: Sure, you can post a new question and I will try and answer it